# Javascript Send Form with Multiple Rows

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, element

I have a HTML code which is a form with 2 rows (potentially to be a lot more) and a javascript that sends the elements from each row to a server via RESTAPI. I can't get it working. Tried debugging it it's not showing me any errors or response. Can someone please take a look at my code! THANKS in advance!

```
<html><body>
  <form id='myform' method='post'>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td><input type=text name=firstName></td>
  <td><input type=text name=email></td>
  </tr>
  <td><input type=text name=firstName></td>
  <td><input type=text name=email></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td><input type=submit></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body></html>



<script>
var myForm = document.getElementById('myform');
myForm.onsubmit = function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'https://localhost/api', true);

function myFunction(){
for(var i=0;i<myForm.length;i++){
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('myform').rows[i]);
    request.send(formData);
    }
}
request.onload = function () {
    console.log(request.response);
    };
}
```

Comment: What's the API?

Comment: @jhpratt it's backend api that requests authentication. I am able to use a similar script to post row of the form. Now that I need to create a form with more than one row, I am struggling with the array

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled your form element id in the HTML.

Change `<form id='myfrom' method='post'>` to `<form id='myform' method='post'>`.

You'll also need a closing `</script>` tag

Comment: Yes, thanks! I changed it but unfortunately my results stay the same- no response and no error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, which I recommend, I'd do the following:

```
<html>
<body>
<form id='myform'>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="items[0].FirstName"></td>
  <td><input type=text name="items[0].Email"></td>
  </tr>
  <td><input type=text name="items[1].FirstName"></td>
  <td><input type=text name="items[1].Email"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td><input type=submit></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#myform').submit(function() {
             $.ajax({
                 url: 'http://localhost/api/saveitems',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: $('#myform').serialize()
             }).done(function(data) {
                 // check your returned data for success
             });
         });
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

On the server side this will require a few things. First you'll need to create a class that contains the fields that you're passing in, for instance:

```
public class Item {
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
}
```

Then you'll need to have an API endpoint in your application that receives a list of items:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveItems(List<Item> items) {
    // Do whatever you need to do
    return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But with this similar script, I was able to send ONE row of the form via the API. The row consists of first name, last name and email. But ideally I want to create a form with multiple rows and allow post of multiple invitations. I am hoping to not need to touch server side